# FileSystemWatcher не отлавливает notification для "created" event (ручное копирование видит изменение)

Tags: c#, .net, файловая-система

Создал службу, которая следит за изменениями в каталоге расположенном на серевере. Служба установленна на нем же. В каталоге специальной программой создаються .xlsx файлы. Суть в том, что, когда происходит событие created, информация об измененном файле записывались в .txt файл.

```
public class WatcherService : ServiceBase
{
    public const string wsName = "WatcherService";
    private FileSystemWatcher _watcher;

    private object _obj;

    public WatcherService()
    {
        this.ServiceName = wsName;
        this.CanStop = true;
        this.CanPauseAndContinue = true;
        this.AutoLog = true;
    }

    protected override void OnStart(string[] args)
    {
        _obj = new object();

        _watcher = new FileSystemWatcher(@"C:\SomeDirectory", "*.xlsx");
        _watcher.NotifyFilter = NotifyFilters.Attributes | NotifyFilters.CreationTime | NotifyFilters.DirectoryName |
            NotifyFilters.FileName | NotifyFilters.LastAccess | NotifyFilters.LastWrite | NotifyFilters.Size;
        _watcher.Created += OnCreated;
        _watcher.EnableRaisingEvents = true;
    }

    protected override void OnStop()
    {
        _watcher.Dispose();
    }

    private void OnCreated(object source, FileSystemEventArgs e)
    {
        lock (_obj)
        {
            using (StreamWriter writer = new StreamWriter(@"C:\Test\Log\WinServiceLog.txt", true))
            {
                writer.WriteLine(String.Format("{0} файл {1} был {2} в каталоге {3}", 
                                               DateTime.Now.ToString("dd.MM.yyyy hh:mm:ss"), e.FullPath, e.ChangeType, _watcher.Path));
                writer.Flush();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Когда файл генерируется автоматически, ничего не происходит. Скопировав файл в каталог, используя Commander получил файл.

1. Переполнения буфера нет (всего один файл в минуту).
2. Код обработчика слишком мал, более того в ручном режиме ведь видит событие.

Дело в какой-то специфике программы? Или генерируется событие, которое не перехватывается?

Comment: `файл генерируется автоматически` Как? Чем? И да, хорошо бы пример кода с `FileSystemWatcher`.

Comment: имеется в виду программа его создает. Я хотел сказать, что вызов события вручную срабатывает, а когда программа создает файл нет реакции.

Comment: @defaultlocale дописал вопрос

Comment: сообственно такое количество "NotifyFilter" не надо, просто решил проверить, вдруг что-то не до конца понял.

Comment: Пока не вижу проблем с этим кодом. Набросал [простую программу](https://gist.github.com/defaultlocale/9e6f05b417684252a3af7d5b54b4c091) она нормально выводит созданный внутри самой программы файл. Нужно подумать в чем еще может быть проблема. Как именно создаются файлы? Обработчик `OnCreated` точно не вызывается (может там блокировка срабатывает)?

Comment: @defaultlocale, программа создает файл на основании вычтенных данных. О самом коде ничего не скажу, программа не моя. Не совсем понял Ваш вопрос об обработчике. Я так понимаю, когда система види изменение в каталоге, она создает оповещение. Watcher его получает и создает событие, а событие обрабатывается в обработчике OnCreated, так? О какой блокировке идет реч? Ведь если бы блокировалась директория при ручном копировании не вызывалось бы событие и не создавался бы файл.

Comment: Как будто, система не делает file change notification для программного файла. Или, какое-то другое уведомление, раз watcher не видит его.

Comment: Я имел ввиду что файл лога может быть заблокирован. Если Вы проверяете возникновение событий только через лог, то имеет смысл убедиться, что проблема именно с событием, а не с логом.

Comment: Предложите вариант проверки. Сам сравнительно недавно пргограммирую, поэтому и спрашиваю.

Comment: Поставить точку останова и проверить в режиме отладки, вывести в консоль или в новый файл.

Comment: Сейчас попробую

Comment: Кстати, вариант. Кроме события `Created` подпишитесь на событие `Renamed`: `watcher.Renamed+=OnCreated;`. Возможно, та программа создает временный файл и перемещает его потом.

Comment: @defaultlocale, а из фильтров какие оставить?

Comment: Сработало? Если изменения файлов не отслеживаете, то должно быть достаточно `FileName`.

Comment: Понял, спасибо.

Comment: Да пожалуйста! Так получилось или нет? :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Предлагаю подписаться на событие [`FileSystemWatcher.Renamed`](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.io.filesystemwatcher.renamed?view=netframework-4.8) и посмотреть что получится:

```
_watcher.Renamed += OnCreated;
```

Возможно, программа записывает данные во временный файл, а затем переименовывает его или перемещает в конечную папку. В этих случаях событие `Created` не возникает.

Поведение можно воспроизвести на таком коде:

```
using System;
using System.IO;
using System.Threading;

class Program
{
    static void Main()
    {
        var watcher = new FileSystemWatcher(@"C:\SomeDirectory", "*.xlsx") {EnableRaisingEvents = true};
        watcher.Created += (s,e) => Console.WriteLine($"Created: {e.FullPath}");
        //Если эту строку закомментировать, то создание файла не будет отловлено
        watcher.Renamed += (s,e) => Console.WriteLine($"Renamed to {e.FullPath} from {e.OldFullPath}");

        var guid = Guid.NewGuid();
        //Создаем файл *.xls
        File.Create($@"C:\SomeDirectory\{guid}.xls").Close();
        Thread.Sleep(1000);
        //Переименовываем его в *.xlsx
        File.Move($@"C:\SomeDirectory\{guid}.xls", $@"C:\SomeDirectory\{guid}.xlsx");
        Thread.Sleep(1000);
    }
}
```

Можно попробовать воспользоваться свойством [`RenamedEventArgs.OldFullPath`](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.io.renamedeventargs.oldfullpath?view=netframework-4.8) чтобы проверить что именно делает программа с выходными файлами.

Comment: Вы были правы. Ключ состоял в том, что программа, генерировавшая файл не вызывала событие "watcher.Created". Нужен "watcher.Renamed". Огромное спасибо)